# Fraction class with documentation

Tags: beginner, ruby, unit-testing, rational-numbers

I have never worked with Ruby before, and thought I'd start working on learning it. For my first little implementation, I have created a simple fraction class. It would be nice if someone would check what I did wrong or could improve upon. I am coming from a JavaScript background which is classless for the most part which is why I might have made some mistakes. Also please rate my documentation, I'm not too familiar with yard just yet.

Here's my code so far:

```
class Fraction

    @top
    @bot


    # top is the x in (x/n)
    # bot is the n in (x/n)
    def initialize top, bot
        @top = top
        @bot = bot
    end

    # Add two fractions to eachother
    #
    # ==== Example
    #  Fraction.new(1, 5) + Fraction.new(2, 3)
    #
    #
    # @param [Fraction] the other fraction
    #
    # @return [Fraction] the sum of the fractions
    #
    # * other must be a fraction
    # * other must be valid as a fraction
    def +(other)
        lcm = Fraction.lcm(@bot, other.bot);
        min = (@bot<other.bot) ? @bot : other.bot

        Fraction.new(@top * other.bot + other.top * @bot, min * lcm).simplified;
    end

    # Access @top
    # @return [Number]
    def top
        @top
    end

    # Access @bot
    # @return [Number]
    def bot
        @bot
    end

    # factors to a number
    #
    #
    # ==== Example
    #
    #  Fraction.factors 12 # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
    #
    # @param [Number] the number to get the factors from
    #
    # Will return a list of factors including 1
    def self.factors number
        return (1..number).to_a.select do |i|
            number % i == 0
        end
    end


    # GCD (Greatest Common Divisor)
    #
    # ==== Example
    #
    #  Fraction.gcd 24, 36 # => 12
    #
    # this works because both 24 and 36 are divisible by 12,
    # but no higher number
    #
    # @param [Number, Number] two numbers to get the GCD from
    # @return [Number] GCD
    #

    def self.gcd a, b
        ((factors a) & (factors b)).pop
    end

    # LCM (Least Common Multiple)
    # ==== Example
    #
    #  Fraction.lcm 3, 5 # => 15
    #  Fraction.lcm 5, 5 # => 5
    #  Fraction.
    #
    # @param [Number, Number] two numbers to get the LCM from
    # @return [Number] LCM
    #

    def self.lcm a, b
        min = (a>b)?a:b

        while true do
            if min % a == 0 && min % b == 0 then
                return min
            end

            min += 1;
        end
    end


    # Simplified
    #
    # ==== Example
    #
    #  Fraction.new(2, 4).simplified # => (1 / 2):Fraction
    #
    # @return [Fraction] a simplified fraction instance
    #
    def simplified
        g = Fraction.gcd @top, @bot

        Fraction.new @top/g, @bot/g
    end

    # Simplified?
    #
    # ==== Example
    #
    #  Fraction.new(2, 4).simplified?            # => False
    #  Fraction.new(1, 2).simplified?            # => True
    #  Fraction.new(2, 4).simplified.simplified? # => True
    #
    # @return [bool] wether simplified or not
    def simplified?
        (Fraction.gcd @top, @bot) <= 1
    end

    # to_s (To String)
    #
    # ==== Example
    #
    #  Fraction.new(2, 4).to_s # => (1 / 2)
    #
    # ==== Format
    #  (#{@top} / #{@bot})
    #
    # @return [String] A formatted string of the *simplified* fraction
    #
    def to_s
        if simplified? then
            sprintf "(#{@top} / #{@bot})"
        else
            simplified.to_s
        end
    end

end




#
# Specs
#
describe Fraction, '+factors' do
    it "should be a list" do
        expect(Fraction.factors(6)).to eq([1, 2, 3, 6])
    end
end

describe Fraction, '+initialize' do
    it "should initialize" do
        expect(Fraction.new(1, 5))
    end
end

describe Fraction, '-to_s' do
    it "should patternize" do
        expect(Fraction.new(1, 5).to_s).to eq("(1 / 5)");
        expect(Fraction.new(6, 5).to_s).to eq("(6 / 5)");
    end
end

describe Fraction, "+lcm" do
    it "should get lcm" do
        expect(Fraction.lcm(5, 3)).to eq(15);
        expect(Fraction.lcm(5, 5)).to eq(5);
    end
end

describe Fraction, '#+' do
    it "should add them together" do
        expect((Fraction.new(1, 3) + Fraction.new(2, 3)).to_s).to eq(Fraction.new(1, 1).to_s)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Mathematical simplification

The `GCD` can be calculated with the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) that is both simpler and faster than your method:

```
function gcd(a, b)
    a, b = b, a % b until b == 0
    return a
```

This also does not need the additional `factors` function.

---

[`lcm` can be defined in terms of `GCD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Reduction_by_the_greatest_common_divisor):

```
def self.lcm a, b
    (a * b).abs / gcd(a, b)
end
```

#### Built-in

Both `gcd` and `lcm` are built-in see: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-gcd and https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-lcm . Maybe you re-implemented them on purpose as part of the exercise but it is good to know how extensive the Ruby Standard library is.

#### Incomplete

The code misses the other operations on fractions (`*/-`) and some useful helpers like `negate (x -> -x)` and `invert (x -> 1/x)`, to become truly useful.

#### Good

Apart from these Math / Completeness matters, the code is very clear (arguably also because it is very simple) and the documentation is comprehensive so good job overall.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really appreciate you taking your time to help me. Sadly I can not upvote your answer, but I can accept it at the very least!

Answer (score 1):

1. Unnecessary stuff: @top, @bot after the declaration of the class.. well, basically you can remove them, what should they do? :O
2. Clarity: @top, @bot - this is mainly matter of taste but... @bot: it's not immediate to understand what it is about (yup, I know it's written in the docs but... couldn't you just have called it bottom?) - or the "real names" numerator / denominator ?
3. Test cases: honestly... unless you do something more than just assigning values, I'd skip the unit test on the initialization.. otherwise, strictly speaking, you'd have to test also top & bot methods, wouldn't you? Makes no sense, doesn't it? ;)
4. Accessors: in ruby we have a nice construct not to have to write all boilerplate code like you did.

We have the equivalence between

```
def top
   @top
end

def bot
   @bot
end
```

and

```
 attr_reader :top, :bot
```

Have a look at attr_writer & attr_accessor as well :)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I went for top and bot for it's simplicity. I did not know about attr_reader, so thank you!